# How to convert numeric to strings in the box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot the boxplot of the following dataset :

```
A = [150, 112, 108, 70]
B = [260, 90, 165, 100]
C = [160, 50, 90, 60]
D = [110, 20, 35, 70]
E = [105, 450, 45, 200]
```

One way I can do it is via the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties( size=18)

Positions = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
Heat = [150, 112, 108, 70, 260, 90, 165, 100, 160, 50, 90, 60, 110, 20, 35, 70, 105, 450, 45, 200]

groups = [[] for i in range(max(Positions))]
[groups[Positions[i]-1].append(Heat[i]) for i in range(len(Heat))];

b = plt.boxplot(groups, patch_artist=False);
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
plt.rc ('xtick', labelsize=16)
plt.rc ('ytick', labelsize=18)

for median in b['medians']:
    median.set(color = 'r', linewidth = 2)
```

I can get the following box plot but I want the numbers 1...5 to be replaced by A...E? Is there an alternative way I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert a char to an integer, use

```
ord(char)
```

To convert an integer to a char, use

```
chr(int)
```

An example:

```
int_array = list(range(5))
char_array = [chr(x + ord('A')) for x in int_array]
# char_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Comment: How would it relate to the specific example i have?